# How to sort MS Access report by group pages

Tags: sorting, report, ms-access-2016

I have a grouped report.
Whenever a new group starts, I set 'Me.Page' to 1.
The number of pages for each group, I am storing in a table in the 'PageFooter_Format' event.
How can I sort the groups by their number of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you can't as the grouping takes place before formatting the report.

Perhaps in a multi-step: First run the report and retrieve and save the group ids and page counts, then close the report, adjust the source to hold the page counts to order by, change the report grouping/sorting to respect this sequence, and run the report.

Comment: Thank you. This I was already thinking about. I just wondered, if there would be a more "beautiful" way.